# What exception is thrown if I try to read a file that doesn't exist?

Tags: dart

I want to read a file like this:

```
try {
  final contents = await new File('myfile').readAsString();
} on SomeException catch (e) {
  // handle it
}
```

What is the exception that I should catch to handle the case where the file does not exist?  Unfortunately it's not defined in the documentation for the `readAsString` method.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm embarrassed to say that I didn't even think of running the code to generate an exception.  And yet not as embarrassed as I would be if I had written a sarcastic comment such as yours.  Next time try not to belittle the person asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ken White pointed out, the solution can be found by generating an exception and printing the answer:

```
FileSystemException
```